# Longer delay for the launchimage?

Tags: ios

I need to show the launchimage for more than 2 seconds.
For this, I'm adding an imageview in viewdidload of the home view controller and after 2 seconds I'm removing it.
But, it was not setting accurately in the bounds of the screen `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`.

Comment: Why, your aim should be to get past the default image as fast as possible...

Comment: It's client requirement, to show about their logo.

Comment: What you are using for calculating the time?? NStimer or something else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at creating a completely separate controller for this. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, create an instance of that controller and then `[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:XXX animated:NO completion:nil];`.

This controller should display whatever image / animation you want and contain a timer, when the timer fires it dismisses itself (`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`).

Comment: It's not working in applicationDidFinishLaunching: , But working fine in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: .

Comment: Thank you Wain for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
sleep(1);
```

Using the above statement in the very first line of

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

the problem I stated was solved easily. 
But we have to use this for smaller delays.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

In removeSplash methos remove the splash screen. Change the delay as you need.

Comment: we are using the same code as stated by you, but the image frame was not setting to the entire screen. I used 


    splashImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
    splashImageView.frame=self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:splashImageView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

Comment: set the auto layout property of image. Issue was you are setting image frame using ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds). Instead check the orientation of the device then set the height and width accordingly.

Comment: can you please print the frame of self.view in NSLog and check what it come.

Comment: we did the same, it gives (768,1004) for iPad, (320, 568) for iPhone 5

Comment: Ok what happen with the image.. is it cut or problem related to orientation. can you post any screen shot of it

Comment: It's being shrunk vertically. we checked with autolayout property also.

Comment: What is the size of the image you are using and the image view??

Comment: We're using "Default" image for that imageview. And, ImageView's frame is    [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds

Comment: I think it was due to status bar. which is taking the 20 pixel of screen height. My suggestion is use the default image with the exact height which you are getting in NSLog. i.e 1004 for ipad and 568 for iphone. Or do one thing hide the status bar. This will solve your all problems. In that case you have to increase the height of viewcontroller by 20 pixel as status bar will be not there

Answer (score 0):

Add your image to main application window in

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

And get width & height using

```
float width = self.window.frame.size.width
float height = self.window.frame.size.height
```

then remove it using a function hideSplash

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];` in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application`

For this solution to work you need to set launch images which can be set either in plist or General setting of product.